# Postgres return multiple rows from nested subquery select statements

Tags: postgresql

Im getting an error with this query, not certain how to solve it.  Without the IN clause using single ID is fine, but the IN is creating subqueries which is blowing everything up.

```
select company_name from users 
where id =  (select COALESCE(master_user_id,id) from users where id IN (30, 34, 242))
```

`Error: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

Comment: for an equal, your sub query must return only one row. If you want all the rows, must be an IN. may be works better if you convert your where in inner join.

Comment: DUH! lol.  Please post your solution and I will accept.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular join:

```
SELECT u1.company_name
FROM users AS u1
   JOIN users AS u2 ON u1.id = COALESCE(u2.master_user_id, u2.id)
WHERE u2.id IN (30, 34, 242);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `IN` instead of `=` as pointed out by commenter Frank

```
select company_name from users 
where id IN  (select COALESCE(master_user_id,id) from users where id IN (30, 34, 242))
```